# Xcode 13 warning for .swiftsourceinfo

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing a framework for iOS, it mixes Swift and Objective-C inside, distributed in binary form without source code.

Since Xcode 13, I observe a warning when importing this framework:

> 'MyFramework.framework/Modules/MyFramework.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo'
> is either malformed or generated by a different Swift version. Note
> that it uses an unstable format and may leak internal project details,
> it should not be distributed alongside modules

It seems it doesn't like .swiftsourceinfo file. Maybe I should just manually remove this file from the package, but I cannot find any explanation of what it is made for.

Even when I set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES, Xcode builds the framework with that .swiftsourceinfo file. So why does the warning say "it should not be distributed alongside modules"?

What is the purpose of .swiftsourceinfo file? Can I safely remove it from the built framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you building your binary frameworks?
Generally, `.swiftsourceinfo` are not stable across different versions of Swift Compiler so shouldn't be included when distributing the framework (especially when `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`). So they shouldn't be included in the .framework package. If you build your framework using `xcodebuild archive` it should not generate `.swiftsourceinfo`

Comment: I've checked the build script - it uses `xcodebuild build`. I've also noticed that another framework which is built as `xcarchive` using Fastlane - it doesn't contain that `.swiftsourceinfo`. I think archive is the correct way for distribution. Thanks for pointing on that, I'll test how it works.

Comment: Yeah, so if you just replace the `build` with `archive` it technically should work as expected and no longer should produce the `.swiftsourceinfo`.